# js Parsing error: Unexpected token )' Line:13 Column:35

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript code as below and I get this error:

```
js Parsing error: Unexpected token )' Line:13 Column:35
```

How can I solve it?

```
/**
 * @param {String} tweet
 * @returns {String[]}
 */
module.exports = function (tweet) {
  var tweets = tweet.split(" "); //превращаем строку в массив
  var result = []; // создаем пустой массив
  for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
    if (tweets[i].indexOf("#") !== -1)  {
      result.push(tweets[i].slice(1, )); // добавляем в массив result хэштег без первого символа #
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

Comment: Would you mind asking a real question ?

Comment: Though there is no question, your problem is the syntax error `.slice(1, )`

Comment: Parsing error: Unexpected token )' Line:13 Column:35    result.push(tweets[i].slice(1, ));    In this place is . simbol (dot simbol)  How can it be parsing error?

Comment: the splice method is taking two arguments here since you've added a comma but you have not specified the second argument. If that was indeed your requirement, I suggest you remove the comma as only the first argument is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, now it works: module.exports = function (tweet) {
  var tweets = tweet.split(" "); //превращаем строку в массив
  var result = []; // создаем пустой массив
  for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
    if (tweets[i].indexOf("#") !== -1)  {
      result.push(tweets[i].slice(1)); // добавляем в массив result хэштег без первого символа #
    }
  }
  return result;
};

Answer (score 0):

It was a sintax error.

```
result.push(tweets[i].slice(1)); // this is the right line
```